# MFC dll modeless dialog Edit Control keyboard input blocked by host application

Tags: dll, plugins, mfc

I am developing CorelDraw plugin using MFC, but when I try to create a modeless dialog, whose parent window is CorelDraw window, but CorelDraw has some default shortcut keys which are single letter, I cannot input those letters in MFC Edit Controls, i am so confused!

This is the dialog creating code:

```cpp
INT_PTR nHandle = m_app->Application->AppWindow->Handle;
HWND hAppWnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(nHandle);
//switch MFC state
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
//CDR app window handle
CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(hAppWnd);
MsgDialog* pDialog = new MsgDialog();
pDialog->Create(IDD_DIALOG1, pWnd);
pDialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: This looks like you are evading CorelDraw's [Custom Tool](https://community.coreldraw.com/sdk/w/articles/172/creating-custom-tools-in-coreldraw-and-corel-designer) framework. CorelDraw doesn't know about this window and cannot consider it when negotiation where any particular user input goes.

Comment: Thanks for the reminding, I just resolved this by using Mutilthread, the reason that I didnot follow  the framework provided by CorelDraw is it didn't mention about creating a dialog, so I changed to MFC. Frankly speaking, the whole plugin system is obscure

Comment: *"I just resolved this by using Mutilthread"* - That is unlikely. You simply exchanged one issue for another issue, with far reaching consequences: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)